# install.packages configure.vars use more than one lib

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying install packages in R, using the command:

```
install.packages('gdtools', configure.vars="INCLUDE_LIB=path1 path2")
```

but this command is wrong. How can I connect the two `include` paths?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I think you are missing some things in your code. How about trying: `install.packages('gdtools',configure.vars =" --with-gdtools-include= path1" )`. There is a detailed explanation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/install.packages.html)

Comment: @blair
Have you found a solution? It is really needed for me, if you can share it, it would be great!